# pyHook library Pyhook.PumpWaitingMessages returns nothing

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyhook, pythoncom

So, I've been trying to play with this a little, and I have this next bit of code

```
def KeyboardEvent(event):
    global log
    log.append(chr(event.Ascii))
    print log
    return True

hooks_manager = pyHook.HookManager()
hooks_manager.KeyDown = KeyboardEvent
hooks_manager.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

Whenever I write something, I automatically get it printed out to me.

However, I want to to have stopping condition for the pumping. 
I've looked online, and found that I can replace `pythoncom.PumpMessages()` with `pythoncom.PumpWaitingMessages()` and then I can put it in a while loop.

However, When I run the exact same code with `pythoncom.PumpWaitingMessages()` inside a while True loop, all I get when i `print log` is nothing. null, empty spaces, weird Ascii things I can't understand, or stuff like this

> ['\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00', '\x00']

I have no idea why this happens, The only thing I need is to find a way to stop pumping messages when I needed.